# Add Auto-Increment ID to existing ascending column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pre-existing table, containing 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'rgtime' and 'ip'. But now I want an auto-increment column.

I am trying to add **ascending** values of `'rgid'` **auto-increment** according to **ascending values** of `'rgtime'` registration time

How do I add auto-increment column by by ascending values of 'rgtime'

This makes random auto increment values for id

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;
```

But is not what I want.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Create new table of the same structure but with id field. Then run a query

```
INSERT INTO MyTable2 SELECT NULL, * FROM MyTable ORDER BY rgtime
```

then check whether everything is OK, then delete MyTable and rename MyTable2 to MyTable

Comment: According to the question, he should add "order by rgtime" as well.

Comment: Oh yes. Had it in mind but forgot. Thanks. Btw, you can always edit an answer adding any stuff you find necessary

Comment: You can do all of this (CREATE, INSERT, INDEX) in a single query, if you like.

Comment: It's not OK, because the 2 tables have different number of fields. So you should set the field list the same as MyTable in the statement.

Comment: NULL is unacceptable in this case by my test. Maybe it's correct `INSERT INTO MyTable2(....) SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY rgtime`